# Input redirection to for and while

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell-builtin

Just out of curiosity,

This command works:

```
$ <file cat
```

But neither of these do:

```
$ <file for
bash: for: command not found...

$ <file while
bash: while: command not found...
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [POSIX grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02) is written that way. A command is defined as:

```
command          : simple_command
                 | compound_command
                 | compound_command redirect_list
                 | function_definition
```

Where a simple command is

```
simple_command   : cmd_prefix cmd_word cmd_suffix
                 [...]
```

and both `cmd_prefix` and `cmd_suffix` eventually allow redirections. For compound commands, there's only the `redirect_list` at the end that allows them, nothing to allow it in the front.

It doesn't exactly *have* to be like this, e.g. Zsh accepts this just fine:

```
% > output for x in a b c ; do echo $x; done
% cat output 
a
b
c
```

But that's Zsh being incompatible, since in standard shells the leading redirection forces the `for` command to be parsed as a regular simple command, meaning that the following is *valid* and the shell will try to find and run a command literally called `for` (with five arguments, and stdout redirected). Giving the error you saw:

```
$ > output for x in a b c
bash: for: command not found
```

(In Bash in particular, the whole input line is parsed first, so if you give Bash the whole `for-do-done` from the first example on a single line, it just drops a syntax error for the `do`, and doesn't execute the `for` before that.)

If I had to guess, I'd expect the root reason for the definition is that it's always worked like that, and so the standard has codified it like that.

Though note that there has been [discussion](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1276#c4509) about changing the standard in this regard. (Probably no-one in their right mind actually relies on `> output for ...` meaning a command called `for` instead of the shell loop).

Comment: see also https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1276#c4509

Answer (score 6):

`for` and `while` are not commands, they are reserved words that start a loop header. You can use redirection for the whole loop but it must be at the end.

This does **not** work:

```
<file for((i=0;i<3;i++)); do read line; echo "$line"; done
```

This **does** work:

```
      for((i=0;i<3;i++)); do read line; echo "$line"; done <file
```

Comment: +1 Redirections are allowed as prefix or suffix to a _simple command_, but not to a compound command (only as suffix).